# Rename files with mv find and awk

Tags: bash, awk, find

Please help with my problem - I need to rename files in bash.

I have this command:

```
 find /opt/media/rec -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.mp4' -mmin +60 -exec basename {} \; -exec mv {} \; -exec awk -F_ -v OFS="_" '{sub(/\.[^.]*$/,"",$3);$3=gensub(/-([^-]*$)/,"_\\1","g",$3);gsub(/\./,"-",$3);print $3,$1,$2,$4}' {} \;
```

But I've got error: missing argument to

> find /opt/media/rec -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.mp4' -mmin +60 -exec
>   basename {} \; -exec mv {} \; -exec awk -F_ -v OFS="_"
>   '{sub(/.[^.]*$/,"",$3);$3=gensub(/-([^-]*$)/,"_\1","g",$3);gsub(/./,"-",$3);print
>   $3,$1,$2,$4}' {} \; now_720p_2014-05-19-18.12.46.266-FET_0.mp4 mv:
>   after «/opt/media/rec/now_720p_2014-05-19-18.12.46.266-FET_0.mp4»
>   missing destination file operand after Try `mv --help' for more
>   information.

What's wrong with my bash command?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is,

```
find ... -exec mv {} \; ....
```

`mv` command requires minimum two arguments. So, It should be,

```
find ... -exec mv first_arg second_arg \; ...
```

That's why you are getting `mv: missing destination file operand after` .

**Test:**

```
$ mv somefile 
mv: missing destination file operand after `somefile'
Try `mv --help' for more information.
```

Comment: How can i use the second argument as awk ?

Comment: @NZT, You mean second argument as `awk` output?

Comment: Yes, awk transform filename to the correct name. How to use this correct name to rename files?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [rename](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename). For example:

```
rename htm html *.htm
```